# SAML - Generating Metadata File for Service Provider

Tags: xml, metadata, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I have a handful of code blocks but am unsure of how to use it all coherently.

Our office (IdP) is going to be using box.com (SP) using simplesamlphp, and we are supposed to provide them a metadata file for SSO handshaking. They provide us with this example file: [view here](https://www.box.com/shared/3isa8qvvqn)

Looking at it, I am unsure of what has to be changed (aside from the x509 certificate block). I have not worked with anything this complex before using SAML.  Is all the content in this file necessary?  And if not, what parts are mandatory that have to be modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running this page on my local machine did it;

http:// 127.0.0.1/simplesaml/www/admin/metadata-converter.php (Your url may vary with virtual host addresses)

I enter the XML example code provided in the link above, then paste it into the text area field provided on this page.  Submit, and it's converted to the necessary saml20-sp-remote.php code.